# how to make ruby block return an array of variable in the block?

Tags: ruby, block

in a ruby block:

```
user.trips.each { |trip| trip.pickedpost.user }
```

How can I make the code return an array of users?

If I run the block

```
user.trips.each { |trip| puts trip.pickedpost.user }
```

irb shows

```
#<User:0x007fd1ab9e2148>
#<User:0x007fd1aacf3dd8>
 => [#<Trip id: 18, pickedpost_id: 25, volunteer_id: 33, created_at: "2012-05-14 23:28:36",    updated_at: "2012-05-14 23:28:36">, #<Trip id: 20, pickedpost_id: 20, volunteer_id: 33, created_at: "2012-05-15 00:12:39", updated_at: "2012-05-15 00:12:39">]
```

the block returns an array of trip object, which is not what I want.

How can I make the block return an user array?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you want is to [`.collect()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-collect) it:

```
user.trips.collect { |trip| trip.pickedpost.user }
```

Or using `.map()`

```
user.trips.map(&:pickedpost).map(&:user)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem! user.trips.map(&:pickedpost).map(&:user)

Comment: `user.trips.map { |trip| trip.pickedpost.user }` might not be as elegant but should be more efficient since it only iterates over the array once.